# Move childhtml from product/view.phtml to product/view/description.phtml

Tags: magento-1.8, layout, blocks

under my theme's config.xml, below layout block used to trigger product reviews and it's form.

```
<reference name="content">
.............
<block type="review/product_view_list" name="review.list" as="review_list" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
  <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
    <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
      <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
      <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
    </block>
  </block>
</block>
</reference>
```

and using `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_list') ?>` in my themes `product/view.phtml` to display review with review form.

Now i'm trying to use `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_list') ?>` in `product/view/description.phtml` but it's showing empty.

Any solution to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you lauout xml file add review block as a child to description block under `catalog_product_view` handler.

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.description">
        <block type="review/product_view_list" name="review.list" as="review_list" template="review/product/view/list.phtml">
            <block type="review/form" name="product.review.form" as="review_form">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="product.review.form.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Review Form Fields Before</label>
                    <action method="setMayBeInvisible"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
             </block>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: Thanks oleksii.svarychevskyi it worked. But one small bug after adding this, i'm getting **one new empty tab** titled **Customer reviews**

Comment: I don't know the exact problem, but it shout be connected with html code of review block. Try to investigate `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\review\product\view\list.phtml`.